# java.lang.RuntimeException: view android.widget.TextView being added, but it already has a parent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, layout-inflater, android-windowmanager

I am using broadcastreceiver to display the values from SMS where i am using WindowManager to display it. But i am getting an Runtime exception which says it already has parent.

```
 WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_check_sms,null);
                        TextView otpnum = (TextView)linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.optnum);
                        otpnum.setText(m.group(0));
                        otpnum.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
                        windowManager.addView(otpnum,params);
```

Where my XML file is below.

```
<LinearLayout

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.snatarajan.otpreader.CheckSMS"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/optnum"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: The TextView already has a parent, the LinearLayout. Add the LinearLayout  to the WindowManager, instead of the TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`otpnum` has already a parent which is `linearLayout`.

So you maybe want to add the whole layout:

```
windowManager.addView(linearLayout,params);
```

or create a seperate xml which only includes your TextView and add that.